# How to change the value of a variable inside an if-statment and apply in all in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, if-statement, variable-declaration

I am creating a feature in my chat bot that changes the bot agent name. I declare the name of the bot at the top.

```
bot = "Bot"
```

Then I create a function that takes input from the user and changes the name of the bot

```
    elif "c-a" in inp:
        settt = True
        print(f"Choose agent(1-7):", end=' ')
        while settt:
            s_c = input()

            try:
                s = int(s_c)
            except ValueError:
                s = str(s_c)

            sv = type(s)

            if sv is int:
                if s == 1:
                    bot = "Bhaskar"
                    return bot
                elif s == 2:
                    bot = "Divya"
                    return bot
                elif s == 3:
                    bot = "Nayan"
                    return bot
                elif s == 4:
                    bot = "Sruti"
                    return bot
                elif s == 5:
                    bot = "Gagan"
                    return bot
                elif s == 6:
                    bot = "Ruchi"
                    return bot
                elif s == 7:
                    bot = "Abhishek"
                    return bot
                else:
                    a()
                    print("I didn't get it. Chose between 1 to 7 or type /h for help & /q for discard")
                    q()
            else:
                if s == "/h":
                    bot_list()
                elif s == "/q":
                    settt = False
                else:
                    a()
                    print("I didn't get it. Chose between 1 to 7 or type /h for help & /q for discard")
                    q()
```

But the value of the bot remains the same. It will not change.

Comment: If `bot` is a global variable, then you need to add `global bot` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: assign the return of the function to the `bot` variable. the `bot` inside the function has no relation to the `bot` outside. also, avoid globals.

Comment: Tip: consider using a dictionary for the names: `{1: "Bhaskar", 2: "Divya", ...}` to avoid all the repeated code (`elif`).

Comment: I am just learning python so i am not handy with that...

Comment: i will try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the variable `bot` is a global.
Inside your function before the `if else` statements add this line

`global bot`

So the code would look like this:

```
bot = "bot"

def name():
    global bot
    #if else statements begin here
```

Comment: File "chat2.py", line 75
    global bot
    ^
SyntaxError: name 'bot' is used prior to global declaration

Comment: Did you add `global bot` to the very top of the function?

Comment: elif s == 3:
                    global bot
                    bot = "Nayan"
                    print(f"{bot} agent set.")
                    return bot

Comment: no you have to add it before the else statements, I'll edit my answer to show the code

Answer (score 0):

You should add `global bot` line to your function. But I suggest to avoid global variables. I think you should give it as parameter and return the changed variable.

```
def your_function(param=None):
    ... Some code (Here you can use the value of bot variable which name is param inside this function.) ...
    return param
bot = your_function(param=bot)
```

It means you overwrite the `bot` variable with return value of your function.

An example:

```
bot = 5
print("Before function: %s" % bot)
def your_function(param=None):
    param = param*2
    return param
bot = your_function(param=bot)
print("After function: %s" % bot)
```

Output:

```
python test.py 
Before function: 5
After function: 10
```